# Iterating Through Treemap Ordered By Comparator

Tags: java, iterator, comparator, treemap

I created an TreeMap that is sorted by value through a Comparator that I passed into the constructor.

How would I iterate through the TreeMap in the order created by the comparator? (Not by ascending value of keys/values)

Comment: Why are you using a sorted map if you want to keep iteration order?

Comment: a) You can't make a `TreeMap` sorted by value.  You can only create something broken.  b) You can't reconstruct the original order.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, you can. http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/java-sort-map-by-value/

Comment: @shmosel I phrased my question poorly, just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @jnara, what that site doesn't tell you is that that approach won't actually work and will create a broken map.  You can't have multiple values with the same key, and it'll throw if you try to do `get(absentKey)` or `containsKey(absentKey)`, or many other operations that maps need to support and that break when you try the hack described on that page.

Comment: Now it makes even less sense. The comparator is used to establish the key ordering. What distinction are you trying to make?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot with a `TreeMap`.

A workarround would be using a `LinkedHashMap` to keep the insertion order.
And as you want to get the map sorted by the `Comparator`, create an
instance of the `TreeMap` with the `Comparator` and  put all elements in that are contained in `LinkedHashMap`.

```
Map<MyObject> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
....
TreeMap<MyObject> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(new MyComparator());
treeMap.putAll(linkedHashMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

`TreeMap` is an implementation of `SortedMap` interface, which

> is ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time.
>   according to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Consider using `LinkedHashMap` to preserve items insertion orderding.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I iterate through the TreeMap in the order created by the
>   comparator? (Not by ascending value of keys/values)

Comparator doesn't create any order! It can only answer the question is the two object it compares are equal(return 0), or the first is greater than second(return value greater than 0), or the first is lesser than second(return value lesser than 0). So, when you pass comparator to TreeMap, you give to the container(with Red-Black tree under the hood) a function which decide to which subtree of binary tree it will add new element using specified key( as in simple binary tree, if key lesser than node it will be added to left subtree, if greater to right, if equals the value under specified key will be replaced(TreeMap doesn't allow duplicate keys)).

And when you iterate over TreeMap, you iterate in ascending(natural) ordering of elements(which have been added to this tree, using your comparator)